# Laravel Validation Rules for Set minimum to 1 when default is 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-validation

I have request array like this

```
{    
    "amenity_rates": [
        {
            "initial_hour": 1,
            "initial_hour_rate": 0,
            "succeeding_hours": 0,
            "is_default": 0,
            "default_rate": 0
        },
        {

            "initial_hour": 1,
            "initial_hour_rate": 0,
            "succeeding_hours": 0,
            "is_default": 0,
            "default_rate": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Now this if the rules of my request

```
$rules =[
    'amenity_rates'                     => 'required|array',
    'amenity_rates.*.initial_hour'      => 'required_if:amenity_rates.*.is_default,0|numeric',
    'amenity_rates.*.initial_hour_rate' => 'required_if:amenity_rates.*.is_default,0|numeric',
    'amenity_rates.*.succeeding_hours'  => 'required_if:amenity_rates.*.is_default,0|numeric',
    'amenity_rates.*.is_default'        => 'required|in:0,1',
    'amenity_rates.*.default_rate'      => 'required_if:amenity_rates.*.is_default,1|numeric'
];
```

Question is I want to set a minimum of this `field('initial_hour','initial_hour_rate','succeeding_hours')` if the `is_default` is 0 when I set `min:1` they throw an error if either `is_default` is 0 or 1.

Comment: You can try to use custom validation rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules)

first run this in your command line

> `php artisan make:rule MinIfDefaultIsZero`

You will find a file called `MinIfDefaultIsZero.php` in `app/Rules` folder

You need to create a constructor that will pass the `is_default` and then validate it in `passes()`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class MinIfDefaultIsZero implements Rule
{
    private $is_default;

    public function __constructor($is_default){
      $this->is_default = $is_default;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if($this->is_default == 0) {
            return $value > 1;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be more than 1.';
    }
}
```